# Unable to add things into my array properly with c

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
int main(void){
    char name[8], comName[24];
    int numComponents, numSchemes, i;


    printf("\n\nHow many marking components in the course? ");
    scanf("%d", &numComponents);
    char *listComponents[numComponents];

    i=0;
    while (i<numComponents){
        printf("\tenter next component name: ");
        scanf("%s", name);
        listComponents[i] = name;
        i++;
    }

    printf("\nThis is name #1 =     %s", listComponents[0]);
    printf("\nThis is name #2 =     %s", listComponents[1]);
    printf("\nThis is name #3 =     %s", listComponents[2]);


}
```

I have this function which asks the user how many names `numComponents` there are, and then initializes an array of Strings that size `*listComponents[numComponents]`.

I then iterate and ask the user for the input and then put it into the array as I go through.
However I'm having a problem where I would input "Math" and then "English" and then "History.

But once I start printing it out to see what the value is, listComponents[0] [1] and [2] are all History.

I was wondering what is causing this and how I would be able to fix it? 
Am I writing into the array incorrectly, or trying to access the array incorrectly, or both?

Comment: this line: scanf("%d", &numComponents); should be: scanf(" %d", &numComponents); (note additional space in format string, to step over leading white space)

Comment: this line: scanf("%s", name); should be: scanf(" %s", name); (note additional space in format string, to step over leading while space, like the '\n' from the prior user entry.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem looks like you are creating an array of character pointers and then setting each array element to point to the same buffer. Therefore each array element will print whatever the last value you wrote to the buffer.

If you want to have an array of N different inputs better to create N *new* strings and store pointers to the *new* strings. Have a look at, for example, [***`strdup()`***](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) (or maybe `strndup()` for the safety concious). Remember to `free()` allocated memory :)

For example

```
while (i<numComponents){
        printf("\tenter next component name: ");
        scanf("%s", name);
        listComponents[i] = strdup(name); //<---- pointer notice **copy** of buffer stored, not     pointer to buffer :)
...
...
<snip>
...
...

for(i=0; i<numComponents;++i) free(listCompoents[i]);
```

The way you do it you get

```
listComponents[0] ----- points to ------> name[]
listComponents[1] ----- points to ----/
listComponents[2] ----- points to ---/
...
listComponents[n] ----- points to -/
```

So, you can see they all point to the same buffer, or area of memory, so printing each will always yield, at any time, the string in `name[]`

Using `strdup()` you get

```
listComponents[0] ----- points to ------> new buffer in memory holding copy of name[]
listComponents[1] ----- points to ------> new buffer in memory holding copy of name[]
listComponents[2] ----- points to ------> new buffer in memory holding copy of name[]
...
listComponents[n] ----- points to ------> new buffer in memory holding copy of name[]
```

**NOTE**: When copying any user input, although I have used `strdup()` you may want to use `strndup()` to avoid large user input or user input that has overrun your `name[]` buffer. If you are `malloc()ing` a constant buffer size and then `strcpy()ing` you defo want to use `strncpy()` to avoid overflowing your allocated buffers

Comment: Thanks Jimbo, I was able to read up more on strdup and it makes sense now.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with this line

```
listComponents[i] = name;
```

you realize that `name[]` is just one array and everytime the loop iterates and reads the user input to `name[]` it is overwriting to the same address space (thats pointed by `name`).. moreover, every iteration assigns a new address to `listComponents[i]` its actually storing the same address of `name[]` at all the places

What you can do is use `malloc()` to achieve what you want, like

```
while (i<numComponents){
    printf("\tenter next component name: ");
    name = malloc(20);
    scanf("%s", name);
    listComponents[i] = name;
    i++;
}
```

and change the `name` declaration to `char* name;`

Answer (score 0):

If you use char array, not char pointer, it will work

```
char name[8], comName[24];
int numComponents, numSchemes, i;
int MAX_CHAR = 10;

printf("\n\nHow many marking components in the course? ");
scanf("%d", &numComponents);
char listComponents[numComponents][MAX_CHAR];

i=0;
while (i<numComponents){
    printf("\tenter next component name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    strcpy(listComponents[i] , name);
    i++;
}

printf("\nThis is name #1 =     %s", listComponents[0]);
printf("\nThis is name #2 =     %s", listComponents[1]);
printf("\nThis is name #3 =     %s", listComponents[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(void)
{
    char name[8]; = { '\0' }; // note: this may be too short for some component name
    char comName[24]; // the compiler should give a warning about unused variable
    int numComponents = 0; 
    int numSchemes; // the compiler should give a warning about unused variable
    int i = 0; // index/loop counter


    printf("\n\nHow many marking components in the course? ");
    if( 1 != scanf(" %d", &numComponents) ) // note: leading space in format string
    { // then scanf() failed
        perror( "reading number of components with scanf" );
        return( 1 );
    }

    // implied else

    char *listComponents[numComponents] = { NULL );

    for( i=0; i<numComponents; i++ )
    {
        printf("\tenter next component name: ");
        if( 1 != scanf(" %s", name) ) // note: leading space in format string
        { // then, scanf() failed
            perror( "reading component name with scanf" );
            return( i+1 ); // +1 so will not return good indication of 0
        }

        // implied else

        listComponents[i] = malloc( strlen(name) + 1 );
        if( NULL == listComponents[i] )
        {
            // free malloc'd areas in listComponents[]
            for( i=0; i< numComponents; i++ )
            {
                free(listComponents[i]); // note: calling free() with NULL is ok
            }
            perror( "malloc" );
            return( numComponents ); // return a positive value error code
        }

        // implied else

        strcpy( listComponents[i], name );
    }

    for( i=0; i<numComponents; i++ )
    {
        printf("\nThis is name #%d =     %s", i, listComponents[i]);
    }

    // free malloc'd areas in listComponents[]
    for( i=0; i< numComponents; i++ )
    {
         free(listComponents[i]);
    }

    return( 0 );
}
```